# How to position iframes

Tags: php, html, css

How do I position iframes? I have read that I should contain them within a div, but I can't seem to get that to work...

I want the iframes inside the divs so that I may only show a part of the original site on only a part of my site.

```
<style>
#s1 {
height:50%;
width:50%;
float:left;
}
#s2 {
height:50%;
width:50%;
float:right;
}
</style>

<body>

<div id="s1">
<iframe id="my-iframe" src="www.site1.com" scrolling="no" style="position:absolute; top:-150px; left:0px; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999; ">
</iframe>
</div>

<div id="s2">
<iframe id="my-iframe" src="www.site2.com" scrolling="no" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999; ">
</iframe>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you set `float: left` for parent then set `position: absolute` for `iframe` you should choose one of these, if you want to make iframes side by side with float so you don't need use absolute for childrens, remove inline css for iframes and use float for parents. if you want use position absolute then remove floats. if you want to use absolute position for children you should set `position: relative` for parent.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xu90Lcgq/)</kbd>

Comment: I tried to mess around with these settings, but I did not get it to work.
The iframe seemed to allways take priority over the div so the div would never contain the iframes.

Comment: did you see jsFiddle link? it's not what you wanted? / if not, please explain with a picture.

Comment: I see no link posted by jsFiddle, Tried to explain what I want to do in a picture here: http://i.imgur.com/ZauiUlo.png

Comment: Thankyou, I failed to understand that was a link. It is indeed what I wanted, but I am haveing a hard time understanding how to resize the div...Using the provided code I got: http://i.imgur.com/EYNpyhr.png